# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES When Installing Store Release at Android 7.0.0

Tags: android, parse-platform, installation, google-play, android-7.0-nougat

I have an issue with installing MyAPP **Store apk** in **Android 7.0.0**

Please check the following points:

- This issue happens only with Android 7.0.0 OS and others are working fine
- Debug APK is working fine at all OS (7.0.0 and others)
- Signed APK is not working with Android 7.0.0 and return the following error:

> An error occured while deploying the file.

`INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl24783944.tmp/base.apk: META-INF/CERT.SF indicates /data/app/vmdl24783944.tmp/base.apk is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2, but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?`

where the old one is installable and have no issues:

Some updates from old release:

I just remove all content of **Parse Notification Lib** from

1. installation code from the app class
2. remove it from app `build.gradle`
3. remove the jar file
4. remove it from Android Manifest
5. Delete the receiver

Please advice,

Comment: What tool/build pipeline is used for signing the "Signed APK"? This error suggests that either the "Signed APK"  was modified after signing, or that the signing step didn't produce a well-formed APK Signature Scheme v2 signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to fix this problem in my commandline sign process was to do **first** `zipalign` and then `apksigner`. Because `zipalign` changes some bits in the file the signing won't be valid for android >= 7.0

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually

Comment: That is the correct answer, I just upload a version without zipalign.